# No service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter' when using ValidateAntiForgeryToken

Tags: c#, .net, csrf, csrf-token

i'm trying to resolve the Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) vulnerability problem in my .net 6 api that is called by my next js app.

I followed the steps in microsoft documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I was able to get the XSRF-TOKEN value to pass in my request, but i'm getting 500 internal server error when i try to request a endpoint with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter' has been registered.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.DefaultFilterProvider.ProvideFilter(FilterProviderContext context, FilterItem filterItem)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.DefaultFilterProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(FilterProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.FilterFactory.CreateUncachedFiltersCore(IFilterProvider[] filterProviders, ActionContext actionContext, List`1 filterItems)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.FilterFactory.GetAllFilters(IFilterProvider[] filterProviders, ActionContext actionContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvokerCache.GetCachedResult(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerRequestDelegateFactory.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<CreateRequestDelegate>b__0(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at CEF.API.Settings.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) in C:\Apps\CEF\CEF.API\Settings\ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs:line 25
   at CEF.API.Settings.DbContextTransactionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ApplicationDBContext applicationDBContext) in C:\Apps\CEF\CEF.API\Settings\DbContextTransactionMiddleware.cs:line 57
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:7118
User-Agent: insomnia/2023.1.0
:method: POST
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6ImF0K2p3dCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwibmFtZSI6IkFETUlOSVNUUkFET1IgRE8gU0lTVEVNQSIsImVtYWlsIjoic2FAaXJvbm1vdW50YWluLmNvbSIsImp0aSI6IjY0NDU2ZmI4LTUzNDYtNDY4MS1hM2UxLWJiZmZlYzVmZjBkOCIsIm5iZiI6MTY4MzIyMjc3OSwiZXhwIjoxNjgzMjI5OTc5LCJpYXQiOjE2ODMyMjI3NzksImlzcyI6IkNFRklzc3VlciIsImF1ZCI6IkNFRkF1ZGllbmNlIn0.lNu7UE2HGJCZ-ko3DR5BHLjySOq9r5GAc5XoU0PEJZg
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.bkgtOg1lj84=CfDJ8Km_KX4y-IVEhw9rViHBUrmbsbOMzZ8L4sP6jqmxKni_Y-brgf0h4hr3y0Lc9fDFMl2KO1dMwdg3yyu5RQMyfq-3Vkjg36OW_COGoEaD2nbhSXEJ1-dUhg0lC17RKNRRoT2E6L2iz_tTYbZeDCYa6i4; XSRF-TOKEN=CfDJ8Km_KX4y-IVEhw9rViHBUrm8b7uGkLGYnyo9tjuSfBZPDCR9tRXxAeJthTPc0Yp3kG1SWUT-qmexIQUbffBwIuX07rfkfDup2kaInKLR9obRLJQpPUzlyGoMd4Ykk2TbMUEZUJ8WJeWnF9ov4kNtJnd3rHNYt9p9KHj3L3H_DHOXi51m652OcmMeXMDEgL_-qA
Content-Length: 725
xsrf-token: CfDJ8Km_KX4y-IVEhw9rViHBUrm8b7uGkLGYnyo9tjuSfBZPDCR9tRXxAeJthTPc0Yp3kG1SWUT-qmexIQUbffBwIuX07rfkfDup2kaInKLR9obRLJQpPUzlyGoMd4Ykk2TbMUEZUJ8WJeWnF9ov4kNtJnd3rHNYt9p9KHj3L3H_DHOXi51m652OcmMeXMDEgL_-qA
```

> This is my Program.cs:
>
> ```
> var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
> builder.Services.AddCors();
> builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
> builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
> {
>     options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
>     {
>         Version = "v1",
>         Title = "CEF API",
>         Description = "An ASP.NET Core Web API for CEF System",
>         TermsOfService = new Uri("site"),
>         Contact = new OpenApiContact
>         {
>             Name = "Company",
>             Url = new Uri("site")
>         },
>         License = new OpenApiLicense
>         {
>             Name = "Software License",
>             Url = new Uri("site")
>         },
>     });
>
>     //Add documentation to swagger ///summary
>     var xmlFilename = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
>     options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFilename));
>
>     // Include 'SecurityScheme' to use JWT Authentication
>     var jwtSecurityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
>     {
>         BearerFormat = "JWT",
>         Name = "JWT Authentication",
>         In = ParameterLocation.Header,
>         Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
>         Scheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
>         Description = "Put **_ONLY_** your JWT Bearer token on textbox below!",
>
>         Reference = new OpenApiReference
>         {
>             Id = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
>             Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
>         }
>     };
>
>     options.AddSecurityDefinition(jwtSecurityScheme.Reference.Id, jwtSecurityScheme);
>
>     options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
>     {
>         { jwtSecurityScheme, Array.Empty<string>() }
>     });
>
> });
>
> builder.Services.AddDomainDI();
> builder.Services.AddApplicationDI();
> builder.Services.AddInfraDI();
> builder.Services.AddInfraApplicationDbContext(builder.Configuration);
> builder.Services.AddServiceDI();
> builder.Services.AddCrossCuttingDI();
> builder.Services.AddControllers()
>     .AddJsonOptions(options =>
>     {
>         options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
>         options.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth = int.MaxValue;
>
>     });
>
> // Set the limit to 128 MB
> builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(options => { options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 134217728; });
>
> builder.Services.Configure<JWTSettings>(options => builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt").Bind(options));
> builder.Services.Configure<SKPSettings>(options => builder.Configuration.GetSection("SKP").Bind(options));
> builder.Services.Configure<RefiSettings>(options => builder.Configuration.GetSection("WSREFI").Bind(options));
>
> builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
> builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
> builder.Services.AddAuthentication
>                  (JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
>                  .AddJwtBearer(options =>
>                  {
>                      options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
>                      {
>                          ValidateIssuer = true,
>                          ValidateLifetime = true,
>                          ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
>
>                          ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
>                          ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
>                          IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey
>                        (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
>                      };
>                  });
>
>
> builder.Services.ConfigHangfire(builder.Configuration);
> builder.Services.AddMvcCore();
>
> //--> ADDED HERE <--
> builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
>
> var app = builder.Build();
> if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
> {
>     app.UseSwagger();
>     app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
>     {
>         options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
>         options.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.None); //all coltrollers collapsed by default
>     });
> }
>
>
> app.UseHttpsRedirection();
> app.UseAuthentication();
> app.UseAuthorization();
>
> //--> ADDED HERE <--
> app.MapGet("antiforgery/token", (IAntiforgery forgeryService, HttpContext context) =>
> {
>     var tokens = forgeryService.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
>     context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken!,
>             new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false });
>
>     return Results.Ok();
> }).RequireAuthorization();
>
> app.UseCors(x => x
>     .AllowAnyOrigin()
>     .AllowAnyMethod()
>     .AllowAnyHeader());
>
> app.MapControllers();
>
> app.UseDbContextTransactionMiddleware();
> app.UseExceptionHandlerMiddleware();
>
> app.UseHangfireDashboard();
> app.MapHangfireDashboard();
> app.AddJobs();
>
> app.Run();
> ```

I try implementing what the microsoft documentation recomends.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the code, before builder.Build()

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute());
});
```